# How to get required folder URL using java swings?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am using Netbeans for java application. during my application at one point i want particular folder URL to store files. how can i achieve this. please can anyone help me..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why would you be looking to use the path to a `File` on the local file system as if it were an `URL`?  An `URL` is particularly unsuited to 'storing files', you are better off keeping the `File` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`JFileChooser`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), with [`JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#DIRECTORIES_ONLY) Take a look at this tutorial: [How to Use File Choosers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to select a folder in a swing application, right? you can use JFileChooser http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

to select only a folder, look at this example
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0370.html

for the saving, check
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

if you need something clarified, just ask.

Comment: 2nd link highlights what i want ...Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want a Open File Dialog box.
In Swing it is called [JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Usage example:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(yourJFrame);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    // Do stuff with file
} else {
    // User clicked cancel
}
```

yourJFrame should be the JFrame you use for your main window. If you don't have one put `null`.